# How to convert a python bytes object with "\x" in the string to int?

Tags: python, integer, byte

I have a `bytes` object in Python.

```
>>> x = b'\x02'
```

How do I convert this into an int?

```
>>> int(x, base=16)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-34d0edaac324>", line 1, in <module>
    int(x, base=16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'\x02'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use int.from_bytes(byte_object, endian type, signed=)

[Helpful Guide](https://appdividend.com/2021/04/09/how-to-convert-python-bytes-to-int/)

[Understanding endian types](https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/)

```
integer = int.from_bytes(x, "big", signed="True")
```